# LINQ Group and Distinct

Tags: linq

I am still working through understanding LINQ.  Below is my SQL that I am trying to convert.  I would like the distinct Ident's whose Max Seq equals the class.

```
SELECT es.Ident
FROM   EqpSeq es
INNER JOIN EqpSeq esMax on esMax.Ident= es.Ident
WHERE    es.Class = 4
GROUP BY es.Ident, es.Seq
HAVING   es.Seq= Max(esMax.Seq);
```

The data looks like

```
Ident     Seq     Class
10        1       4
10        2       5
10        3       4
```

The result of when the Class = 4 should be

```
Ident
10
```

The result of when the Class = 5 should be null.

I thought that this LINQ query might work but it is returning two rows of Ident 10.

```
from es in EqpSeqs
join esMax in EqpSeqs on es.Ident equals esMax.Ident
where es.Class == 4
group es by new {
   es.Ident, es.Seq
} into g
where g.Key.Seq == g.Max(p => p.Seq)
select new {
   Ident = (int?)g.Key.Ident
}
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.  In would be interested to see a LINQ fluent style also.

Comment: Did you try adding `Distinct` to the end of your query? After the `Select`

Comment: Are you sure your SQL query is correct? From your data it seems that none of the rows have `Class == max(Seq)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your replies.  I sat down this morning before leaving for work and talked out loud what I wanted and came up with the following, not sure if this is the most efficient:

```
SELECT es.EqpIdentID
FROM   EqpSeq es
WHERE  es.EqpClassID = 4 and 
       es.Seq = (SELECT Max(Seq) FROM EqpSeq esMax WHERE esMax.EqpIdentID = es.EqpIdentID)
```

The corresponding LINQ produced by Linqer is:

```
from es in db.EqpSeqs
where
  es.EqpClassID == 4 &&
  es.Seq == 
  (from esMax in db.EqpSeqs
  where
  esMax.EqpIdentID == es.EqpIdentID
  select new {
  esMax.Seq
  }).Max(p => p.Seq)
select new {
es.EqpIdentID
}
```

The LINQ Fluent/Method syntax would be:

```
EqpSeqs
  .Where(es => es.EqpClassID == 4 &&
               es.Seq == EqpSeqs
                 .Where(esMax => esMax.EqpIdentID == es.EqpIdentID).Max(a => a.Seq))
  .Select(b => b.EqpIdentID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, given your sample data it is not surprising that you get the same value twice.  You are joining the table to itself on `Ident` but the value of `Ident` is the same in every row.  The result of the join is, essentially, the Cartesian product of the rows:

```
es.Ident  es.Seq  es.Class  esMax.Ident  esMax.Seq  esMax.Class
10        1       4         10           1          4
10        1       4         10           2          5
10        1       4         10           3          4
10        2       5         10           1          4
10        2       5         10           2          5
10        2       5         10           3          4
10        3       4         10           1          4  // This row matches
10        3       4         10           2          5
10        3       4         10           3          4  // So does this row
```

As was suggested, adding `Distinct` to your query should solve this:

```
(from es in EqpSeqs
join esMax in EqpSeqs on es.Ident equals esMax.Ident
where es.Class == 4
group es by new {
   es.Ident, es.Seq
} into g
where g.Key.Seq == g.Max(p => p.Seq)
select new {
   Ident = (int?)g.Key.Ident
})
.Distinct();
```

There are a couple of different queries you could try, as well.

I use the `Ix-Main` NuGet package often, myself.  That package comes with the very handy `MaxBy` function.  If you don't mind adding that package you could do this:

```
EqpSeq 
.GroupBy(x => new { x.Ident, x.Seq })
.MaxBy(x => x.Key.Seq)
.SelectMany(x => x)
.Where(x => x.Class == 4)
.Select(x => x.Ident)
.Distinct();
```

You could do the same thing without `Ix-Main` like this:

```
EqpSeq 
.Where(x => x.Seq == EqpSeq.Max(y => y.Seq) && x.Class == 4)
.Select(x => x.Ident)
.Distinct();
```

Off the top of my head I am not sure which of the three queries would be the most performant.  If the `Seq` column is indexed then my bet would be that the third query is probably the winner.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this is not taking care of the issue either.  I will sit down with a clear head tonight and look through your syntax to see if I can come up with a solution.  As I stated in the problem the SQL query returns what I am looking for, "Find all idents that are associated with a class and whose seq is the maximum for the ident (e.g. The final assignment for the ident was to the desired class).  Thus the result for Class 5 is Ident 10 because its final assignment (Seq=3) was to Class 5, but the result for Class 4 is null because it has a Seq of 2 while the max is 3.